# Lifting vehicles (and spawners) using InterActors, strange collisions causing flying vehicles

Tags: unreal, map-editor

Making a VCTF map with the Unreal Tournament 3 Editor, and thus have vehicles in it. Currently I have 2 walkways next to each other (Big enough for a vehicle). One of them (A InterActor) drops down, and a grate covers the hole until the vehicle respawns. Once its respawned the InterActor Walkway lifts the vehicle up (and the grate pulls back). However what I'm finding is that the vehicle seems to collide with something when it gets near the top.

(Looks something like this: ----_ where _ is the moving InterActor and - is a walkway)

I created a new map to test this, and found it seems the front of the scorpion collides with the walkway in front of it, however I don't know why, it physically (in terms of how it looks in game) does not touch the walkway in front of it, but its actions look like it has.

Im using InterActors, and a vehicle spawner, looking like so

[image: Setup]

How do I stop this from happening? Right now everything is perfect, except the vehicle keeps flying away every time its lifted up, likes it been forced in between the "lift" and another object!

Comment: Is the other object a custom mesh created by you or another? Have you set up the proper collision mesh for it? I know UDK has some problems with holes in geometry and collisions where you would have to build multiple collision meshes around the hole to accommodate.

Comment: The objects I'm using are all Unreal Tournament meshes, I believe the walkways are in the Draco_Floor package